# AS3: Join array and save to textfile is creating blank entries

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, air, text-files, filestream

I'm having a hard time trying to get my array to save correctly into a textfile. The text file is formatted in a one-entry-per-line fashion thus I use this:

```
var newFavString:String = arFavourites.join("\r\n");

    favStream.open(favFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    favStream.writeUTFBytes(newFavString);
    favStream.close();
```

But somewhere, somehow it's adding blank lines which may be caused by spaces within some of the array entries but that shouldn't affect the joining process I don't think.

I used this to clean up the arrays just in case and it still shows some undefined objects in the trace:

```
for (i=0; i<arFavourites.length-1; i++) {
        if (arFavourites[i] == undefined) {
        arFavourites.splice(i,1);
        }
        trace(arFavourites[i]);
    }
```

And this is how I am importing the data into the array:

```
var favFile:File = File.userDirectory;
favFile = favFile.resolvePath("favourites.txt");
var favStream:FileStream = new FileStream();

var arFavourites = new Array();
var FavCount:int = 0;

favStream.open(favFile, FileMode.READ);
var fileContents:String = favStream.readUTFBytes(favStream.bytesAvailable);


    arFavourites = fileContents.split("\r\n");

    for (i=0; i<arFavourites.length-1; i++) {
        if (arFavourites[i] == undefined) {
        arFavourites.splice(i,1);
        }
    }

favStream.close();
```

When I remove something, I search for it in the arrays and splice it out. Maybe the error is there.

```
var k:int;
    var i:int;
    trace("Selected Index: " + dg.selectedIndex);
    if (dg.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (k=0; k<dg.length; k++) {
        if (dg.isItemSelected(dg.getItemAt(k))) {
            for (i=0; i<arFavourites.length; i++) {
                if (arFavourites[i] == dg.getItemAt(k)[1]) {
                    arFavourites.splice(i,1);
                    }
                if (arFavourites[i] == dg.getItemAt(k)[2]) {
                    arFavourites.splice(i,1);
                    }
                if (arFavourites[i] == dg.getItemAt(k)[3]) {
                    arFavourites.splice(i,1);
                    }
                if (arFavourites[i] == dg.getItemAt(k)[4]) {
                    arFavourites.splice(i,1);
                    }
                if (arFavourites[i] == dg.getItemAt(k)[5]) {
                    arFavourites.splice(i,1);
                    }
            }
            dg.removeItemAt(k);
            dg.scrollToIndex(k);
            dg.clearSelection();
            break;
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<arFavourites.length-1; i++) {
        if (arFavourites[i] == undefined) {
        arFavourites.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    var newFavString:String = arFavourites.join("\r\n");
    trace(newFavString);

    favStream.open(favFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    favStream.writeUTFBytes(newFavString);
    favStream.close();
```

When something is added or removed from the array, the text file is updated.
I'm sure its something really simple and I would greatly appreciate a speedy response =) 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally figured out a working solution. 
By getting the `selectedIndex` I could figure out which array element matched the dataGrid line and then splice it out.

Selected Index:

```
arFavourites.splice(dg.selectedIndex*5,5);
```

Remove row from DataGrid:

```
for (k=0; k<dg.length; k++) {
        trace(dg.length);
        if (dg.isItemSelected(dg.getItemAt(k))) {
            dg.removeItemAt(k);
            dg.scrollToIndex(k);
            dg.clearSelection();
        }}
```

ReWrite text file:

```
var newFavString:String = arFavourites.join("\r\n");
    trace(newFavString);
    favStream.open(favFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    favStream.writeUTFBytes(newFavString);
    favStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really not the way to filter things out from an array (you doing it both inefficiently and missing some):

```
private function test():void
{
    var tester:Array = [];
    tester[1] = 1;
    tester[2] = 2;
    tester[4] = 3;
    tester[6] = 4;
    // 1-2-3-4
    trace(removeEmptyElements(tester).join("-"));
}

public static function removeEmptyElements(array:Array):Array
{
    var result:Array = new Array(array.length);
    for (var i:int, j:int; i < array.length; i++)
        if (array[i] != undefined) result[j++] = array[i];
    result.length = j;
    return result;
}
```

This would be the way to do it. You would also want to consolidate the if statements testing for mutually exclusive conditions (or does `getitemAt` have a side effect?). Otherwise it looks more like a bug.

Comment: Thanks man this helped =) If it wouldn't be too much to ask, could you take a look at the 'remove function'. Something is just not working and I can't for the life of me figure out what. It's got something to with the `getItemAt` command. My logic is to match the selected line in the `datagrid` to the entries in the array and remove them from the array, then update the text file. If I `trace(dg.getItemAt(k));` I get `[object Object]` So confusing..

Comment: TextFile(favourites.txt) > Array(arFavourites) > DataGrid(dg) - My Display. I have 2 buttons that add and remove from the datagrid. So the process is then - Remove from DataGrid, Remove from Array, ReWrite TextFile.